Is $x^p−t$ irreducible?
What is an example of a field extension of degree $2$ which is not Galois?
Here is the answer I found

It is written that
The most typical example of a non-separable extension is $\Bbb F_p(t^{1/p})/\Bbb F_p(t)$ for a prime $p$; this has degree $p$ so if you take $p=2$ you have your answer.

However, it states in the comment box that
The minimal polynomial of $t^{1/p}$
is $x^p−t$
. This is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$
by Eisenstein's criterion.
My confusion :why is $x^p−t$ irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p[t]?$
My thinking : Suppose  $p=2$, then $x^2-t=(x-\sqrt{t})^2$  which  is reducible
$\implies x^p−t$ reducible over $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$
Note : User last seen more than one year ago so I'm posting this, otherwise, I can leave a comment.

maybe $\sqrt{t}\in\mathbb F_p[t^{1/2}]$, but $\sqrt t\not\in\mathbb F_p[t]$

$t$ is a prime in the UFD $\mathbb{F}_2[t]$. Apply Eisenstein: the constant term of $x^2-t$ is divisible by the prime $t$ but not by $t^2$. The leading coefficient, $1$, is not divisible by $t$. The remaining coefficients are $0$, hence divisible by $t$. By Eisenstein's Criterion, $x^2-t$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2[t]$. Same argument for any prime $p$ replacing $2$.
Your argument fails for the simple reason that $\sqrt{t}$ is not in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_2[t]$. What made you think it was? By your argument, $x^2-2$ would not be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Surely you do not claim that...

okay that  mean $x^2-t$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2[t][x]=\mathbb{F}_2[t]$.Am i right ? @Arturo Magidin Sir .

@jasmine $\mathbb{F}_2[t]$ is the ring of polynomials in the variable $t$ and coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2$. $\mathbb{F}_2[t][x]$ is the ring of polynomials in the variable $x$ and coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2[t]$. What on Earth makes you claim the two are equal?

I apologize for the delay in responding @Arturo  Magidin sir . It was my bad judgment  that  $\mathbb{F}_2[t]=\mathbb{F}_2[t][x]$ . This means that  the polynomial $x^2+t$ is irreducible over both $\mathbb{F}_2[t]$ and $\mathbb{F}_2[t][x]$.Am i right ?

@jasmine Again, not really. "over $\mathbb{F}2[t][x)$" (meaning, polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}[t][x]$), this expression is a constant. I proved it is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[t][x]$, and irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2[t]$. First expression tells you which ring you are working in.  Second is for polynomials only and tells you where the coefficients are.

I get it now,thanks you sir @Arturo Magidin

$x^p-t$ is irreducible as a polynomial in $\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}} \F_p[t][x]$ if and only if $x^p-t$ is irreducible as a polynomial in $\F_p[x][t]$ (because $\F_p[t][x] \cong \F_p[x][t]$).
But the latter is clearly true as $x^p-t$ is a degree one polynomial in $\F_p[x][t]$.

I don't understand why is $x^p- t$  a degree one polynomial ? I think $x^p-t$  is  a degree $p$ polynomial

@jasmine Degree 1 in the polynomial ring $(\mathbb{F}_p[x])[t]$. The variable there is $t$, not $x$.
